# EF automatic migrations backwards compatible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have an `EF 6.13 + MVC 5` website running on Azure and I am trying to use *Azure's Deployment Slots* which is basically having always 2 (or maybe more) sites running while using the same DB and different versions of the source-code, think of it as **Slot1** has current production code and **Slot2** has the *vNext* code.

The issue I'm having is that when there's a migration in **Slot2**, even if we make it so that compatibility is not affected, then *EF* will complain about the DB not being in the same version as the *Model*.

I have read this questions:

- [EF backward compatible DB migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914395/ef-backward-compatible-db-migrations)
- [How can I disable model compatibility checking in Entity Framework 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623260/how-can-i-disable-model-compatibility-checking-in-entity-framework-4-3)

but in both cases they ensure *EF* won't complain about Model compatibility by making it *NOT CHECK* compatibility at all using some variation of this:

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("myConnString")
    {            
        //Disable initializer
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(null);
    }
}
```

There is however a few things unclear to me:

- If I change the Model Compatibility checks and no migrations are run automatically, then how do I migrate my DB?
- Can I make my `DbContext` check model compatibility and warn me only if it's broken (like I deleted a column or something like that, not that I added another column, I know this can be troublesome but bear with me and assume I have a plan for these kind of events)

Answer (score 0):

*If I change the Model Compatibility checks and no migrations are run automatically, then how do I migrate my DB?*

I have a good answer for you here:
[Dis-Advantages of using EF 6.x.x Code First without Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695220/dis-advantages-of-using-ef-6-x-x-code-first-without-migration/37697001#37697001)

*Can I make my DbContext check model compatibility and warn me only if it's broken (like I deleted a column or something like that, not that I added another column, I know this can be troublesome but bear with me and assume I have a plan for these kind of events)*

It is not easy to do that. The problem is that you have to decode the Model on the fly and compare it with Model column of the `MigrationHistory` table.

---

This link might be also interesting for you:

https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/

https://romiller.com/2013/02/05/extending-and-customizing-code-first-models-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, I've been going over the links you gave me but their goal is not what I'm looking for. I want to different versions of the code "talking" to the same database (which would be in a compatible status).

Comment: So you have an application is made for example with EF 4.3 and the other application is made with EF 6 and you have one database? Is that exactly what you want?

Comment: I have two versions of the same app, just a few git-commits different, but some of those commits can have migrations, I'm interested to know if there is a way to have both versions working on the same DB for a short time before they're both on the same version again, few days at most.